# Complexity of a code in c programming language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, complexity-theory

I am wondering if the complexity of this code is O(n) or is it O(count*n)? I made the parameter count and it is not dependent on the parameter n as you could see:

```
void change(int A[], int n, int x)
{
  int i, j, count=0;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    if(A[i]==x)
     { count++; }
  }
  
  for(i=0; i<count; i++){
     for(j=0; j<n-i; j++){
         printf("Hello World"):
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: "it is not dependent on the parameter n" - if your A array is full of value x then it is.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* service. You could first try some *experimental* approach: measure the time (see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)), draw a chart of it, and try to guess. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O -g` then use [GNU gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/)

Comment: @Rup sorry I changed it to A[i].

Comment: The `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O foo.c -o foo-bin`  is the command line you should use to compile a source file `foo.c`  into an executable `foo-bin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop is `Theta(n)`. The time complexity of the second loop (as you've found depends on the value of `count`) is:

```
T(n) = n + (n-1) + ... + (n-count) = O(n * count)
```

Therefore, the final time complexity is  `O(n * count)`. And as `count = O(n)`, we can say the time complexity is `O(n^2)` in terms of `n`.

Comment: but since we have: 

T(n) = n + (n-1) + ... + (n-count) .       don't we take the biggest value which is (n) and ignore the rest?

Comment: This is how this works, since this the big-O notation tracks worst-case complexity, and the worst-case is that `count == n`

Comment: @AhmadIstaitih We do not know the value of the `count`. As I've said in the worst-case `count = n`! Hence, the worst time complexity is `O(n^2)` and you can't ignore the value of the `count`.

Comment: If the number of elements in `T()` is constant, then each of them contributes `O(n)`, and the total is `O(const * n) = O(n)`. However, in this particular expression, the number of elements is itself `O(n)`, and therefore, the net complexity is `O(count * n) = O(n * n) = O(n^2)`